# How to solve dateTime Ranges in Bot Framewok?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Ciao, i get issues with converting DateTimeResolution into DateTime, how can i do it?

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DateTimeResolution]'.

```
  private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ValidityToStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var addUserDetails = (UserDetails)stepContext.Options;

            var res = Convert.ToDateTime(((List<DateTimeResolution>)stepContext.Result).FirstOrDefault()?.Start);
            addUserDetails.MembershipValidityTo = res;

            if (addUserDetails.MembershipValidityTo == null)
            {
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter Validity To Date", "Please enter Validity To Date", InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                var RetryPromptMessage = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter a valid Date (ex: 20/08/2020), date must be greater or equal than Today");
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(AddUserDialog)}.validityTo", new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = promptMessage,
                    RetryPrompt = RetryPromptMessage
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(addUserDetails.MembershipValidityTo, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the way you do it now? So we can focus on what's wrong rather than how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've added it

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution i just created built entity DateTimeV2 and made Resolve Method.

Method was taken from this topic: [Using the prebuilt entity datetimeV2 to capture daterange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954515/using-the-prebuilt-entity-datetimev2-to-capture-daterange)

```
private IList<Dictionary<string, string>> DateTimeResolutor(WaterfallStepContext stepContext)
        {
            IList<Dictionary<string, string>> resolutionValues = null;
            var culture = Culture.English;
            var r = DateTimeRecognizer.RecognizeDateTime(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text, culture);
            if (r.Count > 0 && r.First().TypeName.StartsWith("datetimeV2"))
            {
                var first = r.First();
                resolutionValues = (IList<Dictionary<string, string>>)first.Resolution["values"];
                var asString = string.Join(";", resolutionValues[0]);
                var subType = first.TypeName.Split('.').Last();
                if (subType.Contains("date") && !subType.Contains("range"))
                {
                    // a date (or date & time) or multiple
                    var moment = resolutionValues.Select(v => DateTime.Parse(v["value"])).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else if (subType.Contains("date") && subType.Contains("range"))
                {
                    // range
                    var from = DateTime.Parse(resolutionValues.First()["start"]);
                    var to = DateTime.Parse(resolutionValues.First()["end"]);
                }
            }
            return resolutionValues;
        }
```

And after that i just get start and end date for my variables:

```
var startDate = dateRange.FirstOrDefault()?["start"]);
var endDate = dateRange.FirstOrDefault()?["end"]);
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Also i do this:

```
startDate = dateStart == DateTime.MinValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(((List<DateTimeResolution>)stepContext.Result).FirstOrDefault()?.Value) : startDate;
```